# How to sharpen an image in CSS?

Tags: image, css, image-processing, client-side

If I have an image loaded from an arbitrary URL (local or remote), and do not want to use javascript nor server-side processing, is it possible to sharpen it from client-side with CSS?

Comment: This question could use an updated answer. Does the CSS filter style have a sharpen() filter? It has a blur filter. Can it be achieved with a convolution matrix?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Yes**, for some browsers this is already possible (like Chrome and Firefox).

In particular, you need [`mix-blend-mode`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode) and [CSS filters](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRVdax) with the Lenna image as example, and a (compiled) copy of it as a code snippet:

```css
.foo,
.bar,
.bar::after,
.baz {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  position: absolute;
}
.foo {
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(1.25);
  filter: contrast(1.25);
}
.foo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.bar,
.bar::after,
.baz {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png);
}
.bar::after {
  content: '';
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px) invert(1) contrast(0.75);
  filter: blur(4px) invert(1) contrast(0.75);
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="baz"></div>
```

Hover over the image to see the effect. Tweaking of parameters (and maybe using `opacity` to "fade" the effect, similar to the "intensity" setting of unsharp mask) can help in yielding more desireable results for particular use-cases.

Comment: This is interesting. However, using CSS filters will severely impact the performance of the browser (just hover on the result image and scroll, and repeat without hovering on image, the effect is evident without having to look at frame rate in diagnostic tool). I think this wouldn't be practical in actual real-world usage in the near future, right?

Comment: @Billy Depends - on Chrome I can't even notice that, on Firefox somewhat but only slightly. I can only expect this to get better with time, and "complex" CSS selectors were a performance-killing thing not too long ago, and look where we are now. On the plus side, the radius I chose could be reduced, and if implemented in SVG instead of CSS it *should* be faster because the browser *should* cache the resulting render (but I didn't try it).

Comment: the codepen is missing the image to hover over .. +1 when i used a image to see the effect :)

Comment: Serves me well... I trusted a link shortener! :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a hack that will sharpen downscaled images using CSS.  It only works in Chrome, but from my experience Chrome seems to blur images more so than other browsers.  This will basically "undo" the blurriness and make the image look more like the original.  Layer the image on top of itself using absolute positioning and set `image-rendering` to `pixelated`.  An example is given here:

[Weird CSS hack for sharpening images (Chrome 59 and 60 only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872640/weird-css-hack-for-sharpening-images)

Comment: That does not make it sharper though, it makes it noisier (almost counts as artificial detail). Nearest neighbor is bad for downscaling because it's unpredictable; consider what it would do to a high-res fabric, by sampling arbitrary pixels instead of an average, thus making a grey fabric look full of noisy black and white dots (also consider: halftone scans). Being able to specify sharper algorithms would be good, in order to increase [acutance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acutance).